# MySQL Error 1452 - Cannot add or update?

Tags: mysql

This is my database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/NwEOI.png

I am trying to insert data into my main linking table procedure after inserting data into all the tables around it. I have checked the data being inserted and it seems ok, I have checked my relationships as well.

```
$proceduredata = array 
            (
                'patient_id' => $patientfk,
                'name_id' => $procedurenamefk,
                'department_id' => $departmentfk,
                'dosage_id' => $dosagefk,
                'edocument' => NULL, //not implemented yet
                'user_id' => $this->session->userdata('userID'),
                'duration' => NULL, //not implemented yet
                'submitted' => date('d-m-Y H:i:s', now()),
                'comment' => NULL, //to be implemented

            );

            $insertprocedure = $this->db->insert('procedure', $proceduredata); //inserts into 'procedure' table with $proceduredata array
            $procedurefk = $this->db->insert_id(); //gets the primary key of the row inserted
```

The error message:

> A Database Error Occurred
>
> Error Number: 1452
>
> Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`midas1`.`procedure`, CONSTRAINT `belongs to a` FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) REFERENCES `department` (`department_id`))
>
> INSERT INTO `procedure` (`patient_id`, `name_id`, `department_id`, `dosage_id`, `edocument`, `user_id`, `duration`, `submitted`, `comment`) VALUES (17, 7, 0, NULL, NULL, '2', NULL, '06-07-2011 13:41:01', NULL)
>
> Filename: C:\xampp\htdocs\midas\system\database\DB_driver.php
>
> Line Number: 330

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0):

`$departmentfk` seems to be `0`, but needs to be an ID from the `department` table, according to your constraints in MySQL. MySQL checks the `department` table and doesn't find a corresponding ID, thats why it fails.

Comment: Thanks, it looks like there is something wrong with my form as I have 10 ids and it should be inserting id 1 instead of 0,

Comment: Glad I could help. Consider upvoting or accepting the answer, so that your question doesn't appear in the "unanswered" tab.